# Is it possible to replace the json property in the body response using kong response-transformation plugin?

Tags: kong, kong-plugin, konga

Is it possible to replace the JSON property in the body response using the kong response-transformation plugin? if yes, how to can I accomplish it using the UI Konga?

```
Example of a response body:
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
]
```

what I want is to replace the id for user_id for each user in the response json.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that only with the response-transformation plugin itself, but you can do that with a custom plugin or with Reedelk flow + Reedelk Transformer plugins (you may end up adding your custom logic to some groovy scripts). If you want to try this option, you can read about it here: https://konghq.com/blog/transform-your-requests-responses-with-the-kong-reedelk-transformer-plugin/

Or you may also look for info in the Reedelk Transformer documentation.